# Behavior of creating objects in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

At one time I had a theory that instantiating objects on every request rather than having them reside in the Application scope was a huge memory hog. As my knowledge of ColdFusion has grown over the years, I don't think I really understood how CF deals with classes in the "black box" of the CF framework, so I'm going to ask this for community correction or confirmation.

I'm just going to throw out what I *think* is happening:

1. A CFC is compiled into a class, each method within that CFC is compiled into a class.
2. Those classes will reside in (PermGen) memory and can be written to disk based on CF administrator settings.
3. When a new object is created or template requested, the source code is hashed and compared to the hash stored with the compiled class.

   1. If there is a match, it will use the compiled class in memory
   2. If the compiled class doesn't exist, it will compile from source
   3. If the compiled class exists, but the hash doesn't match, it will recompile.
4. As an aside, whenever you enable trusted cache, ColdFusion will no longer hash the source to check for differences and will continue to use the compiled class in memory.
5. Whenever you create a new object, you get a new pointer to the compiled class and its methods' classes and any runtime events occur in the pseudo-constructor. **Edit:** At this point, I'm referring to using createObject and having any "loose" code outside of functions run. When I say pointer, I mean the reference to memory allocated for the object's scopes (this, variables, function variables).
6. If you request an init, then the constructor runs. The memory consumed at this point is just your new reference and any variables set in the pseudo-constructor and constructor. You are not actually taking up memory for a copy of the entire class. **Edit:** For this step I'm referring to using the new operator or chaining your createObject().init() old school.

This eliminates a huge fallacy that I, personally, *might* have heard over the years that instantiating large objects in every request is a massive memory hog (due to having a copy of the class rather than just a reference). Please note that I am not in favor of this, the singleton pattern is amazing. I'm just trying to confirm what is going on under the hood to prevent chasing down red herrings in legacy code.

**Edit**: Thanks for the input everyone, this was a really helpful Q/A for me.

Comment: I have no idea, but number 2 looks unlikely.

Comment: @Dan, I was thinking that they were just loading into PermGen.

Comment: Great question!!! I have a project coming up that will require the right answer to this question. Thanks for asking it so precisely.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've been developing CF for 14 years and I've never heard anyone claim that creating CFC instances on each request consumed memory due to class compilation.  At the Java level, your CFML code is direct compiled to bytecode and stored as Java classes in memory and on disk.  Java classes are not stored in the heap, but rather in the permanent generation which is not (usually) a collected memory space.  You can create as many instances of that CFC and no more perm gen space will be used, however heap space will be allocated to store the *instance* data for that CFC for the duration of its existsance.  Note, open source Railo does not use separate classes for methods.

Now, if you create a very large amount of CFC instances (or any variable) for that matter, that will create a lot of cruft in your heap's young generations.  As long as hard references are not held after the request finishes, those objects will be cleared from the heap when the next minor garbage collection runs.  This isn't necessarily a bad thing, but heap sizes and GC pauses should always be taken into account when performance tuning an application.

Now, there are reasons to persist CFC instances, either as a singleton pattern or for the duration of a session, request, etc.  One reason is the overhead of actual object creation.  This often involves disk I/O to check last modified times.  Object creation has increased speed significantly since the old days, but is still pretty far behind native Java if you're going to be creating thousands of instances.  The other main reason is for your objects to maintain state over the life of the application/session/request such as a shopping cart stored in session while the user shops.

And for completeness, I'll attempt to address your points categorically:

1. For Adobe CF yes, for Railo, methods are inner classes
2. Yes.
3. Actually, I don't believe there is any hashing involved. It's all based on the datetime last modified on the source file.
4. Yes, but again, no hashing-- it just skips the disk I/O to check the last modified datetime
5. I don't think "pointer" is the right term as that implies the Java classes actually live in the heap.  CF uses a custom URL classloader to load the class for the template and then an INSTANCE of that class is created and stored in the heap.  I can understand how this may be confusing as CFML has no concept of "class".  Everything is simply an instance or doesn't exist at all.  I'm not sure what you mean by "runtime events occur[ing] in the pseudo-constructor".
6. To be clear, the JAVA constructor already ran the instant you created the CFC.  The CF constructor may be optional, but it has zero bearing on the memory consumed by the CFC instance.  Again, I think you're getting unnecessarily hung up on the pseudo-constructor as well.  That's just loose code inside the component that runs when it is created and has no bearing on memory allocated in the heap.  The Java class is *never* copied, it is just the template for the instance.

Comment: I think the memory consumption I was referring to was not the compilation, but actual copy of the classes. It does not make sense when you think about it.

Comment: Yes, I don't believe there are copying of classes going on underneath.

Comment: With respect to "runtime" I meant the loose code outside if init

Comment: Are you absolutely positive about the timestamp? If so, that is great to know!

Comment: As for Railo yes because it's open source and I've read the code.  As for Adobe CF, I can't find any official docs right off that state that but I've looked at a lot of stack traces of apps under load and without trusted cache you will see many calls to the disk subsystem to retrieve the date last modified of the file.  There would be no need to get that data if any other process (such as hashing) were used. Besides, it just makes sense.  Reading the entire file would be MUCH more overhead.

Comment: Yes, Brad, that does make sense. The reason I ask is that this might help us to debug why, when we individually clear a file from the trusted cache using the API that it fails to clear, requiring a full flush. I got the hash theory from Mark Drew back in the day.

Comment: Brad's right. No-one I'm aware of has ever cited overt memory consumption as an argument for or against object reuse as opposed to creating transients @ whim. The case has always been one of performance. One thing I think Brad missed saying is that one shouldn't architect one's CFML application on perceived penalties like this: deal with them IFF they arise. On the whole create a transient when you need a transient, persist an instance in a shared scope when that makes sense, eg: the UserService might last an application's lifetime; a User object will last as long as it's needed.

Comment: I did not mean to suggest this was a widespread belief. It was just sugested that giant cfcs could be a memory issue. I can see in JMC that transients certainly are not an issue. In addition, I wish I would not have even put that as part if the question.

Comment: Note that "giant CFCs" don't mean "more memory", just "giant" .class files (on disk and in PermGen) but, frankly, PermGen is typically small compared to your regular Java heap these days (we run with 8GB heaps and 1GB PermGen). A CFC _instance_ contains a hashmap (variables scope) and that will use as much memory as as your code puts into it - nothing to do with the size of the code. One important note: each method is actually an instance of a (small) Java class and those are added to variables scope - method invocation is dynamic.

Comment: Just to clarify my "method is an object" comment: at runtime, functions in CFML are values that you can pass around, assign to variables and so on - they are small Java class instances with an "invoke()" method that calls their actual compiled code (in PermGen).

Comment: @SeanCorfield I knew about function assignment to variables (and have dealt with issues with private/public methods from it), however, the structure of it is interesting that it's actually being called via an invoke method on the class. I guess that makes perfect sense. Thanks for that bit of information.

Comment: Just to confirm, if you don't save class files, is it comparing some date property of the class file cached in memory when trusted cache is off or you clear a file from trusted cache? Or does it just purge the class from memory?

Comment: You don't "clear trusted cache", you clear your template cache. And  in your scenario, how could you compare a date property of a class file if you cleared it?  Also, when you say "does it purge", what does  _what_ purge?  Sorry, I'm just having problems following your winding question. When a template is needed, the in-memory cache is checked first, then disk cache. If trusted cache is enabled, what's found is used.  If trusted cache is not enabled, the date is checked before it's used.  Clearing template cache only clears the in-memory cache. Disk cache is _never_ purged.